Why PlayStation's reverb only (almost) worked at 22050 Hz?
The no$psx emulator is shipped with extensive docs.
In the SPU reverb section, there's the algorithm and the following note:

The reverb hardware spends one 44100h cycle on left calculations, and the next 44100h cycle on right calculations (unlike as shown in the above formula, where left/right are shown simultaneously at 22050Hz).

This is a bit puzzling as the author uses the suffix h when it talks in hexadecimal units, but in this case, 44100h makes no sense so I suppose it's a typo and Hz are meant instead.
That said, I re-implemented the algorithm and it sounds 99% like the closed-source emulator.
After fiddling with it, it turns out that it can also work at 44100 Hz! (*1)
Sadly, trying to make it working at, say, 48000 Hz, didn't work at all. (*2)
*1 - by multiplying all coefficients by 2 and apply a 22050 Hz LP filter for crazy highs
*2 - upgraded it from shorts to floats, which worked fine for 22050 Hz and 44100 Hz
Question:
So, why is the PS1 reverb stubbornly tied to a multiple of 22050 Hz?

If the hardware such as the chip or clocks that drive it is made to work at a single rate then it does not work at any other rate. For example a CD player and the audio system that processes the audio is made to work only at one specific rate, or in case of oversampling, multiples of that base rate. Are you simply asking why it does not support other rates? If you alter the rate you need to alter the coefficients to have same impulse response at the new rate. You can implement anything in software but the original hardware can't.

@Justme: Additionally, trying to playback a waveform using an output sample rate other than the one with which it is recorded requires a lot of CPU horsepower to do well, but a lot less to do adequately; doing the "adequate" level of processing on a reverb effect, however, is likely to make things sound bad.

@supercat The SPU seems to do that already, it looks like you can select at which rate each channel plays data and the sound chip outputs at a fixed rate of 44.1 kHz.

Per https://github.com/psx-spx/psx-spx.github.io "An important detail to know about this current document, as well as the original from Martin, is that it isn't a clean room reverse engineering project, as some people may seem to believe or repeat. A good chunk of the original document has been either directly copy/pasted from the confidential code and documentation from Sony, or summarized and rephrased." So I'm not sure your opening sentence "The no$psx emulator is shipped with extensive reverse-engineering docs." is accurate.

The audio hardware runs at one fixed sampling rate, 44100 Hz, or rather, one fixed master clock.
In some hardware versions the audio is handled by the DSP of the CD-ROM subsystem which obviously works only on 44.1 kHz sampling rate, as it is fed by a master/system clock of 33.8688 MHz which happens to also be 768×44100 Hz, so a common multiple for serial audio bus. It basically means whatever the DSP needs to do it must do it in 768 clock cycles for each stereo sample, or 384 clock cycles for each individual sample.
Apparently the reverb subsystem DSP cannot perform all the necessary calculations for two channel stereo output at 44100 Hz so the reverbed audio input is first downsampled to 22050 Hz with a 39-tap FIR filter, then the reverb processing is done in 22050 Hz domain and the output is upsampled back to 44100 Hz audio stream for mixing it with the non-reverbed channels for playback through the audio DAC.
So, basically, the sampling rate of the system is 44.1 kHz and the reverb can't be done at that rate so next simple solution is to run it at half speed of 22.05 kHz.
Let's switch to digital signal processing for a moment.
The original chip can't run the reverb in stereo at 44100 Hz rate so it must downsample it to 22050 Hz, run the reverb processing, and upsample back to 44100 Hz for playback with the original 44100 Hz audio stream.
In digital signal processing, you can do things in multiple different ways and end up in same result. For example, your software does not need to downsample by half first, do the processing, and then do the upsampling - in theory there exists an algorithm that will produce an identical result even if you stay in 44100 Hz rate when processing the reverb.
And since 44100 Hz and 22050 Hz have a ratio of exactly 2, the conversion, or dropping the downsampling is simple - for each coefficient in the impulse response, the delay is twice the amount of samples in 44100 rate than 22050 rate. But it is much more difficult to convert only the reverb algorithm to run at 48000 rate. You would need to scale the delays by a non-integer rate of 160/147. And in general, the conversion is not made in one step for efficiency reasons. It is much easier to stay in 44100 Hz land until you need to play the audio out and if for some reason 44100 rate is not possible then let some framework like OS or library code or dedicated sampling rate library handle the final conversion from 44100 to some other target rate for the sound card.

Nice answer although it doesn't explain why it too also works at 44100 Hz...

@aybe I don't know what your code does but your code can do anything at any speed, the original hardware can't. So obviously you can leave out the downsampling/upsampling and run the reverb directly at 44100 Hz rate like the rest of the audio if you change the algorithm to have equal delays. It of course does may not produce an identical result, and it may bring a problem that it sounds a bit different unless you take care of it somehow that it sounds the same than as if it were processed in 22050 Hz by lowpass filtering.
